# Comparing dates from a Class

Tags: python, datetime, oop

So I'm still learning OOP and I'm trying to figure out how to use `datetime` in my exercise.

So I have 2 classes:

`Delivery` - it gets the delivery number, quantity and expiration date.

`Grocery` - It gets a list of deliveries, sorted from newest to oldest by dates.

It also has 2 methods, but I'm stuck on the 2nd one so I'll just post two.

`add delivery` - Just gets a new delivery and adds it to the list

`remove old products` - It checks if any deliveries are expired (using today's date). If so, it removes them from the list of deliveries.

This is my go:

```py
from datetime import datetime, timedelta, date
import time

class Delivery(object):
    def __init__(self, orderNum, quantity, expDate):
        self.orderNum = orderNum
        self.quantity = quantity
        self.expDate = expDate

    def __str__(self):
        return "Order number: {} Quantity: {} Expire date: {}".format(str(self.orderNum), str(self.quantity), self.expDate)

class Grocery(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.deliveryList = []

    def __str__(self):
        return "Delivery list: {}".format(str(self.deliveryList))

    def add_delivery(self, newDelivery):
        self.deliveryList.append(newDelivery)
        return

    def remove_old_products(self, orderNum):
        today = date.today().strftime("%d/%m/%Y")
        expDate = datetime.strftime("%d/%m/%Y")
        print("Today's date is:", today)
        if expDate > today:
            self.deliveryList.pop(orderNum)
            print("Removed old items")
        return

testDelivery = Delivery(123, 4, "29/8/2019")
testGros = Grocery()

testGros.add_delivery(testDelivery)
testGros.remove_old_products(testDelivery.orderNum)
```

I'm getting `TypeError: descriptor 'strftime' requires a 'datetime.date' object but received a 'str'` and I'm not sure how to fix this,

Any help would be great :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `remove_old_products` is missing a bunch of logic. You pass on the order num, but then expect to get the delivery for that order and compare the delivery dates - but you haven't got any code to actually find the delivery and get its expiry date.

You should simplify things by passing in the whole delivery object.

```
def remove_old_products(self, delivery):
        today = date.today().strftime("%d/%m/%Y")
        expDate = delivery.expDate.strftime("%d/%m/%Y")
```

But this doesn't quite work either; you're comparing strings in d/m/y format, but that means that 01/02/2019 comes before 02/01/2019, which isn't right. You should compare the dates directly,

```
def remove_old_products(self, delivery):
        today = date.today()
        expDate = delivery.expDate
        print("Today's date is:", today.strftime("%d/%m/%Y")
```

Now you call the method with the delivery:

```
testGros.remove_old_products(testDelivery)
```

Answer (score -1):

The offending line is this one:

```
expDate = datetime.strftime("%d/%m/%Y")
```

`datetime` is not a datetime object / instance. It's referring to the module itself. The `datetime` module has a `strftime` method, and a given `datetime` instance also has a `strftime` method, but they have different signatures. Since you're using the module `strftime`, you need to pass a datetime object as well as the format string:

```
expDate = datetime.strftime(dt, "%d/%m/%Y")
```

Comment: No, this isn't right. There's only one strftime method, and it's on the datetime class. Your solution works because in Python you can call any instance method from the class by passing in the instance as the first argument. But that doesn't mean that is the right thing to do.